# How do I echo the post term ID for a custom taxonomy in a CPT loop?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to echo the term ID for a custom taxonomy in a cpt loop.
Here is where I am at but can't seem to find a solution.

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'companies', 
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby'=> 'ASC'
)); ?> 

<?php
$taxonomy_prefix = 'company_category';
$term_id = 'TERM ID HERE';
$term_id_prefixed = $taxonomy_prefix .'_'. $term_id;
?>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> 
</div>
```

Suggestions appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $post;
wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'your_taxonomy_name', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```

you can use this function.

Comment: can you give me an example of how this would be used in the loop above to echo the ID?